# instantiating template functions and classes with boost preprocess

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, macros

Working with the seemingly standard `w`, `x`, `y`, `z` demos, suppose I have the following macro trying to be converted to an "iterable" preprocessor macro

```
#define INSTANTIATE_FUNC(rtype, func_name, ...)  \
    template rtype func_name< w > (__VA_ARGS__); \
    template rtype func_name< x > (__VA_ARGS__); \
    template rtype func_name< y > (__VA_ARGS__); \
    template rtype func_name< z > (__VA_ARGS__);
```

For completeness, suppose we're trying to instantiate the following

```
struct w { static constexpr int data = 0; };
struct x { static constexpr int data = 1; };
struct y { static constexpr int data = 2; };
struct z { static constexpr int data = 3; };

template <class Data>
void printData(const std::string &prefix) {
    std::cout << prefix << Data::data << std::endl;
}

INSTANTIATE_FUNC(void, printData, const std::string &prefix)
```

I made a [minimal gist with a build system](https://gist.github.com/svenevs/73af95a841c1851e7c53d1531bead05b) for convenience so that if you are interested in trying you don't have to recreate everything :)

I can't quite figure out how to approach this.  The only functional (but not useful) stab

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/list/for_each.hpp>

#define LIST (w, (x, (y, (z, BOOST_PP_NIL))))
#define MACRO(r, data, elem) template void data < elem > (const std::string &prefix);

#define INSTANTIATE_FUNC(rtype, func_name, ...) \
    BOOST_PP_LIST_FOR_EACH(MACRO, func_name, LIST)
```

This is works, but is clearly not adequate.

1. <del>Why does this not *also* work with sequences?</del>

   ```
   #include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>
   // this does work, my code included the wrong header
   // on what I was testing with (seq/for_each_i.hpp)

   #define SEQ (x)(y)(z)(w)
   #define INSTANTIATE_FUNC(rtype, func_name, ...) \
       BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(MACRO, func_name, SEQ)
   ```
2. How should I approach building `template rtype func_name < {w,x,y,z} > {args,in,__VA_ARGS__}`?  I tried quite a few different things, but the problem seems to be not being able to e.g. only extract `w` and then loop through `__VA_ARGS__`, then continue on.  I've been trying like heck to get [`BOOST_PP_LIST_FOR_EACH_R`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/list_for_each_r.html) to work.  Is this at least the right thing to look at?
3. As a sanity check, you can't define a macro within a macro right?  Something in the spirit of

   ```
   #define INSTANTIATE_FUNC(rtype, func_name, ...) \
       #define MACRO_##func_name(r, data, elem) data < elem > (__VA_ARGS__); \
       BOOST_PP_LIST_FOR_EACH(MACRO_##func_name, func_name, LIST)
   ```

I'm ultimately working toward the goal of enabling optional extension of `LIST` / `SEQ` (`SEQ` seeming *much* easier to achieve this for) if that means anything.  Thanks for any suggestions / resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you need to deliver several pieces of data to your `MACRO` in `BOOST_PP_(LIST|SEQ)_FOR_EACH` and there is only one "slot" that you can use. The thing that you seem to be missing is the fact that you can group those pieces in, for example, a tuple and then access the different elements inside your `MACRO` using `BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM`. Something like this could work:

```
//These are not required, just to help with readability
#define MACRO_GET_RETURN_TYPE(TUPLE)  BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3,0,TUPLE)
#define MACRO_GET_FUNC_NAME(TUPLE)  BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3,1,TUPLE)
#define MACRO_GET_ARGS_SEQ(TUPLE)  BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(3,2,TUPLE)


#define MACRO(_, DATA, ELEM) template MACRO_GET_RETURN_TYPE(DATA) MACRO_GET_FUNC_NAME(DATA) < ELEM > (BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(MACRO_GET_ARGS_SEQ(DATA)));

// with boost seq
#define SEQ (x)(y)(z)(w)

#define INSTANTIATE_FUNC(rtype, func_name, ...) \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(MACRO, (rtype,func_name,BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__)), SEQ)
```

[Live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/H4OrVFdMviAYbkfe)

PS: No, you can't define a macro within a macro, and the code you posted here does work for sequences, the one in your gist does not due to using the wrong header.

Comment: WOW! Yes, I was entirely unaware I could "tuplize" my macros.  This is pure magic and a total game changer.  With this capability I can take it even further than I originally thought.  Muahahaha.  I knew this had to be possible. Thanks for showing me how :) P.S. Yeah, that trailing `i` makes a huge difference for the sequence *faceslap*. As an added bonus, `wandbox` is way nicer than a `gist`...